Find user who have topic Endorsement in salesforce
I want help that when any user got the endorsement on any topic,So i want to count the total endorsement that particular user got.
Example - there is user Adrienne he got 2 endorsement on different topic, so i want to query and count that this user have 2 endorsement
I R&D on this and get about the obj. like know KnowledgeableUser but it may only query once in a day
So, please help me to find out the best way
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4LuOSAV
